# How to print array with jekyll and liquid

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a json document with some data

```
{"teams":[{"team":"Team A","evolution":[1,2]},{"team":"Team B","evolution":[3,4]}]}
```

I try to print it to my view with liquid

```
{% for team in teams %}
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">{{team.team}}</a></td>
    <td>{{team.evolution}}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor%}
```

The html result is

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="#">Team A</a></td>
    <td>12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="#">Team B</a></td>
    <td>34</td>
</tr>
```

But what I would like to print is the raw array for the second `<td>`

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="#">Team A</a></td>
    <td>[1,2]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="#">Team B</a></td>
    <td>[3,4]</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming that you get your datas from a `_data/teams.json` file, this works :

```
{% assign teams = site.data.teams.teams %}
<table>
{% for team in teams %}
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">{{team.team}}</a></td>
    <td>{{team.evolution | join: "," | prepend: "[" | append: "]"}}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor%}
</table>
```